# Making a variable available to all application Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using fingerprints to get the visitorID of the page, and I need to supply that to all the applications or some components. this is what I am doing.

in my App.tsx

```
  .....
  const [visitorId, setVisitorId] = useState("");
  const { clearCache } = useContext(FpjsContext)

  const {
    isLoading,
    data,
  } = useVisitorData();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("LOADING")
    if (!isLoading && data) {
      setVisitorId(data.visitorId)
    }
  }, [data, isLoading]);
```

and I am passing that `visitorId` Below.

```
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme()}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <RedirectProvider>
          <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <Auth0Provider>
              <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                <CustomModalProvider>
                  <UpsellProvider>
                    <Switch>
                      <Redirect exact from='/' to='/dashboard' />
                      <Route path='/signup' component={() => <OnboardApp visitorId={visitorId} />}/>
```

the above is in App.tsx.

but `OnboardApp` goes further with

```
export const OnboardApp = ({ visitorId }: any) => {
  return <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from='/signup' to='/signup/provider' />
    <Route path='/signup/provider' component={ProviderOnboard} />
    <Route path='/signup/seeker/:companyId' component={() => <SeekerOnboard visitorId={visitorId} />} />
    <Route path='/signup/seeker' component={() => <SeekerOnboard visitorId={visitorId} />} />
    <Route path='/signup/user' component={UserOnboard} />
    <Route path='/signup/vendor' component={() => <VendorOnboard visitorId={visitorId} />} />
  </Switch>; 
}
```

so I just to pass on this value of `visitorId` to these components using a better way. I am learning react at the moment so any help would be great. thank you